# update table with join but with summed values

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I've got 2 tables:

```
-Card
id
points

-History
CardId
points
```

Now I would like to perform update query which subtracts points in Card table based on points in History with the same cardId

for example I have rows:

```
-card
1 10
2 30

-History
1 5
1 3
2 10 
2 9
```

and as a result I should have in Card table rows:

```
-card
1 2
2 11
```

what is the best way to do that?

Comment: Why do you need to store this? Are you going to recalculate for the entire table every time an insert/update/delete takes place? You can always calculate this at runtime. I see absolutely no reason to store redundant data and force yourself to maintain the count in an additional place.

Comment: I think we all agree that you're pretty well going about this wrong. Maybe it would be better to give us the scope of intent, and let us help you rework the database. In point of fact, if your "Card" and "History" were combined, and the values of "history" were negative (easy enough to query to find which is which if need be) then the entire process becomes a single `SUM` on the entire table based on id.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This will do it.

```
update card
set points = points - total
from card
    inner join (select cardid, sum(points) as total from history) v 
    on card.id = v.cardid
```

But I agree with other comments questioning your database structures

Comment: ok but I also wanted to add where id > x in history so I just made another nested query